# UINavigationItem barButtonItem customView detecting other items then setting width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationitem

Here is my NavBar

[image]

Now I know how to add a `customView` on the `leftBarButtonItem` by using this code

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.customView = someCustomView
```

As seen on my screenshot here

[image]

But the question is, Is there a way that I could detect if there are any `navigationItem`s next to my `leftBarButtonItem` so I could set the width to be dynamic? instead of overlapping like the screenshots?

Here's more screenshots of my test case

[image]

**Note:** Yes I know how to set the frame by using the code `someCustomView.frame = CGRect(.....)` also it seems that the UINavigationBar/Item inherits from NSObject rather than UIView

**Edit:** So apparently after doing much coding, recoding, and research, the only part of the `UINavigationBar`/`UINavigationItem` that automatically resizes itself according to the **left and right** `barButtons` is the `titleView` which kind of sucks in a way.

So according to my knowledge, the only way to achieve this:
[image]

is by using the `titleView` property of the `UINavigationItem` which doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If -hopefully- these are the outputs that are looking for:

[image]

[image]

Then you should set the [titleView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview) of the navigationItem:

> A custom view displayed in the center of the navigation bar when the
>   receiver is the top item.

It dynamically handles the width to not overlap.

For example, in the follwoing code snippet, I'll set the value of `navigationItem.titleView` as a UILabel (and of course you can customize it):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))
    label.text = "Some very long text that should be in the middle of the navigation bar"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.blue

    navigationItem.titleView = label
}
```

The output should be similar to the screenshots above.

Note that *"Item 01"*, *"Item 02"* and *"Item 03"* that appear in the screenshots are added directly in the storyboard, there is no code related to adding them.

If you want to let the label to at next of "Item 01" button, simply let it:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))
        label.text = "my label"
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = UIColor.blue

        navigationItem.titleView = label
```

Output should be like:

[image]

Hope this helped.

Comment: yeah I've thought of this too but the thing with titleViews is that it's `centered` and not `leftAligned`.

Comment: @ZonilyJame well, if you want to set it as a UILabel (that's what it should in your case), check my edit.

Comment: I've also done that bro, thanks for the effort, but what I'm looking for here is detecting the items in the `NavBar` then setting the width accordingly. Just like how the `NavigationBar Title` automatically truncates itself I'm looking for a way to replicate that behavior, in this case, for a `UINavigationItem`

Comment: I could also just hide the `navigationBar` and add myself a `customView` that looks like a `navigationBar` but I don't wanna stray away from the framework.